# Node addon development - cannot open source file "napi.h"

Tags: c++, header-files, node-addon-api

Just started fiddling around with developing an addon for Node in C++ using Node API (for the first time, I might just add). Everything is working great for the most part - I'm using the built-in compiler in Visual Studio for starting it, debugging and playing around, and `node-gyp` for building it for requiring it in Node. I have an entrypoint for local testing, let's call it `main.cpp`, where my `int main()` function is defined - which is executed when I run/debug my solution in Visual Studio (using Ctrl+F5/F5).

I also have a source file where the 'node communication' is defined (`NodeCommunication.cpp`), and it is this file (among others) that is listed in the `sources` array in my `binding.gyp` file. It is here that `napi.h` is included as well, and its APIs are used. Mousing over the `include` however, there is error text saying "cannot open source file napi.h" - which makes sense, I guess (?) that header file is something that is only injected on build time in `node-gyp` somehow. However it'd be really nice, DX-wise, to be able to resolve those somehow, because right now I have to comment out all the source code in that file before compiling and running the solution in visual studio for testing purposes.

What are my options here? Might as well also attach my `binding.gyp` file for reference.

```
{
    "targets": [
        {
            "target_name": "foobar",
            "sources": [ "NodeCommunication.cpp", "Sample.cpp", "Sample.h" ],
            "libraries": ["../SDK/Library/EDSDK.lib"],
            'include_dirs': ["<!@(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")"],
            'dependencies': ["<!(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').gyp\")"],
            'defines': [ 'NAPI_CPP_EXCEPTIONS' ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you not take the output of that `node -p` command and stuff it in your Visual Studio project's include directories?

Comment: @Botje thank you for the tip. Added the output from both `node -p` commands under `Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories` in Visual Studio, and at least I seem to be getting somewhere :) Still can't compile the project though, but it seems to find the `napi.h` header file now anyway - although now it complains that it cannot find the `node_api.h` file instead, which is referenced in `napi.h`.